# Pyspark: Converting RDD to RowMatrix

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, similarity

I have an RDD of the form (id1,id2,score). The top(5) rows look like

```
[(41955624, 42044497, 3.913625989045223e-06),
(41955624, 42039940, 0.0001018890937469129),
(41955624, 42037797, 7.901647831291928e-05),
(41955624, 42011137, -0.00016191403038589588),
(41955624, 42006663, -0.0005302800991148567)]
```

I want to calculate similarity between id2 members based on scores. I'd like to use RowMatrix.columnSimilarity, but I need to convert it to a RowMatrix first. I want the matrix to be structured id1 x id2 -- i.e., make a row id out of id1 and a column id out of id2.

If my data was smaller I could convert it to a Pyspark dataframe and then use pivot like

```
rdd_df.groupBy("id1").pivot("id2").sum("score")
```

but that borks with over 10,000 distinct id2, and I have much more than that.

The naive
    rdd_Mat = la.RowMatrix(red)
brings the data in as a 3-column matrix, which isn't what I want.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your data more closely resembles the structure of a `CoordinateMatrix`, which is basically a wrapper for an RDD of `(long, long, float)` tuples. Because of this, you can very easily create a `CoordinetMatrix` from your existing RDD.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import CoordinateMatrix

cmat=CoordinateMatrix(yourRDD)
```

Furthermore, since you originally asked for a `RowMatrix`, pyspark provides a way to easily convert between matrix types:

```
rmat=cmat.toRowMatrix()
```

giving you the desired `RowMatrix`.

Comment: Thanks. I found I had to make an intermediate step of transforming the ids into consecutive integers, to avoid making a matrix with 40mm columns.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. No obligation.